# HTML Submit Button not showing up

Tags: html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Calorie Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form">
    <p>Weight in grams: <input type="text" id="weight" size="1"></p>
    <p>Calories per n grams: <input type="text" id="cal" size="1"> n =
      <input type="text" id="n" value="100" size="1"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
  </form>
  <p id="final"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Simple question, the submit button is literally not on the page.

Comment: Do you have any css that might remove it for some reason? I just put this code in a snippet and it shows up fine.

Comment: This must be a matter of the browser you use. I copied your code into a file and started it via DoubleClick. The button shows up.

Comment: Yeah same, Works perfect on my machine

Comment: please provide the css code

Comment: Absolutely no CSS yet, gonna see if it shows up in edge cause I'm using chrome now.
Edit: Not showing up in edge either.

Comment: @Matt, If you press Ctrl+U in chrome, does it show up in the page source?

Comment: You do see it in the snippet above, yes?

Comment: Do you have hide() function?